# Converting bash string variable to quotes separated words

Tags: bash

I have a string variable in bash

```
$ t_partitions='p0,p1,p2'
```

I need to convert this string variable into

```
$ t_partitions=''p0','p1','p2''
```

Can someone help

Here is my attempted solution

```
          t_partitions="p0,p1,p2"
          new="'"

          for (( i=0; i<${#t_partitions}; i++ )); do

          if[${t_partitions:$i:1}==",”];
          then
          $new+="'"
          $new+="${t_partitions:$i:1}” 
          $new+="'"

          else
          $new+="${t_partitions:$i:1}”
          fi

          done
          $t_partitions=$new
```

Comment: I edited. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do this in `bash`:

```sh
t_partitions='p0,p1,p2'
t_partitions="'${t_partitions//,/\',\'}'"
echo "$t_partitions"

'p0','p1','p2'
```

Here `${t_partitions//,/\',\'}` replaces each comma with `','` and we wrap value with `'` at start and end positions using "'${t_partitions//,/','}'"`.